# No Sound through Headphones after recent PulseAudio Updates in Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, sound, updates, pulseaudio

I just recently ran updates on my Ubuntu 12.04LTS and noticed that there were updates to PulseAudio.   Just my luck and I have discovered an issue with no sound via only headphones.   I have verified that I have sound via PC Speakers but when using no headphones no sound at all.

I have also verified that headphones are ok, I have tested them on multiple devices and I'm able to hear sound just fine.

Something must have changed within pulse audio to break sound via headphones, how can I troubleshoot this?

Headphone working perfectly fine until I updated Ubuntu.  What information can I provide to help resolve the issue.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

My headphones use to work as well.  After the update did the following:

[Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working)

Now my headphones work.

Comment: My worked for short period of time now another update has been pushed out and I have to use Alsamixer to turn them on again