# 13.04 hp laptop dv6t intel quad edition no headphone sound when plugged in

Tags: 13.04, sound, alsa, headphones, jack

this is my alsa output
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=5dba3e3cc98914f6dce181eaa548769da5a0e6d8

I have followed this old solution that solved my problem for ubuntu 12.04, but in 13.04 the say solution won't work.
[Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working)

so I have change my OS from ubuntu to linux mint 15 (which is 13.04 based) the old solution still doesn't solve my problem with headphone jack.

when i put my headphone in, the speaker will mute, but nothing will come out from headphone.

many thanks.

I love Ubuntu, it has been my primary OS for the last year for 12.04, I want to upgrade to 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have an HP dv7 on 13.04 with very similar problems. The fix for me is as follows:

Plug your headphones in, and then open a terminal with ctrl+alt+T. Run `alsamixer`. Move to the right so that the "speaker" column (which will be at 0) is highlighted, and then turn it up.

I wish I could offer a more permanent solution (because goodness knows I'd love to know of one too), but this will at least work to get it working (it will continue to work even if you unplug/replug the headphones, but you will have to do it again every time you restart - and probably if you log out and in again, I haven't tested this for myself though)