# Can't hear sound from headphone jack

Tags: 12.04, headphones

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit desktop. I can't hear sound from headphone jack in my pc while speakers are working perfectly. I am very new to linux and I dont have any idea about the audio drivers in Linux. Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue. In my case, however, I could hear sound but it sounded like it was coming out of a very deep cave.

I  changed the balance and that helped. Try that perhaps and see if it helps.

`All settings > Sound > Output`

and try changing the balance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but doesn't help :(

Comment: Can you try looking if any of these help you [headphone-jack-not-working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working)