# Headphones not working in 13.10 after update

Tags: pulseaudio, thinkpad, 13.10, headphones

I'm still unable to get sound to my headphone jack on my IBM ThinkPad T61 after a recent update to 13.10.  When I plug the headphones into the jack, there is sound for about 1 second and then it cuts out.  The laptop speakers work fine.  I've tried editing analog-output.conf and analog-output-headphones.conf but haven't been successful.  I've also uninstalled/reinstalled pulseaudio and have tried using alsamixer.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm pulling my hair out!

Comment: This was the working solution for me: [pulseaudio - Headphone jack not working? - Ask Ubuntu][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Type alsamixer into your terminal. Then scroll with your directional keys to the right until the tab "auto-mut" is highlighted red. If your problem is anything like mine, it will be "Enabled." Hit the up directional arrow to change the status to "Disabled." That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue since 13.10 upgrade. I poked around in alsamixer, sytematically changing settings, and found that if I changed the automute setting to line out. It worked for me, hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: Could you expand your answer to be more clear on what exactly to do? What "automute setting" exactly where?

Comment: from terminal run alsamixer. hit f5 to see all sound drives. scroll to the right and look for <auto-mut> change that to line out.

Comment: Please **edit** your answer to include that. That's how this site works.