# Headphone continuously stops working in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, sound

I think when I first installed 13.10 on my Windows 8 ASUS S550CM, the headphones weren't working.  I tried suggestions in the following questions:

- [Headphones not working in 13.10 after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360697/headphones-not-working-in-13-10-after-update)
- [No audio in Ubuntu after upgrade to 13.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638818/ubuntu-no-audio-after-upgrade-to-13-10)
- [Fix Ubuntu 13.04 sound](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)
- [Headphones not working](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/04/headphones-not-working-no-sound-under.html)

And after a few restarts, with no clear solution, it is just fixed all of a sudden.  A few more restarts and it stops working again.  I go through the same suggestions, restarting, and nothing happens, until eventually I'm restarting for some other reason, and they start working again.

Could this be updates that are enabling/disabling them?  What could be happening here?

### Update

It seems that restarting the computer is not enough.  Once I shut down the computer and turn it on again (without making any other adjustments) the headphones work again.  That seems to be the best solution so far, but I still have no idea why it's happening.

Comment: It may be a problem with the headphones themselves. Sounds more like a hardware problem than a bug in Ubuntu. Have you tested another headset to see if that works or done any other sound tests to isolate the problem?

Comment: @comrademike Headphones work fine in Windows; other headphones also don't work in Ubuntu.  I'm not adjusting the cord or the jack.  Just restarting a couple times seems to fix...  so strange.

Comment: Same on EEEPC (Asus), happens only since march 11 or 12. Not a kernel issue. I installed libav and audacity before the problem happened.