# Headphones not detected on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, acer

I bought a new Acer gateway NE-572 laptop and installed Ubuntu 15.10 on it. Everything is working fine except the headphones. After putting headphones into jack audio is being played by laptop speakers only, no sound from headphones. How to fix the issue?

Comment: Open your Sound Settings and select your headphones. If they aren't under the Output tab, then you have a bigger problem.

Comment: No, headphones option is not there..what else can be the problem? @SuperSluether

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find your headphones in sound settings it hints at a problem with the sound program installation. Try through the terminal opening `alsamixer`, clicking F2, and seeing if you can find them there.

If you find them there then follow the instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure.

If you can't find them there then maybe one of the top two solutions here will help you [Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working).

Good luck!