# Asus X555UJ Laptop internal microphone and 3.5mm stereo jack sound input not working in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, asus, microphone

My laptop internal microphone and sound input is not working. Laptop model is Asus X555UJ.Ubuntu version is 16.04.
I tried the troubleshooting steps mentioned in Ubuntu sound card troubleshooting page (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting) .
But none helped!

Following is my sound card information from pacmd.

```
 $pacmd

  >>> list-sources  

2 source(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE 
priority: 1950
volume: front-left: 99957 / 153% / 11.00 dB,   front-right: 99957 / 153% / 11.00 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max rewind: 0 KiB
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 16.00 .. 371.52 ms
monitor_of: 0
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
module: 6
properties:
    device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
    device.class = "monitor"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf328000 irq 16"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "9d70"
    device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
 * index: 1
name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE 
priority: 9959
volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max rewind: 0 KiB
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 371.52 .. 371.52 ms
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
module: 6
properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = "ALC256 Analog"
    alsa.id = "ALC256 Analog"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "0"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf328000 irq 16"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "9d70"
    device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "front:0"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
    device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
    alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC256"
    alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0256,10431ccd,00100002 HDA:80862809,80860101,00100000"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
ports:
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
active port: <analog-input-mic>
```

Comment: which desktop environment are you using? did you check the basic audio settings? what exactly is not working?

Comment: I'm using the ubuntu default desktop which is Unity 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this thread  [Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working?newreg=7f814973ce284e0a95dcc950b1ba6663)

Solution is,

Run the following command into the Terminal:

gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
Scroll down and add these lines to the end of the file:

```
#Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6-amic
```

Then, save , reboot and test sound using headphones and speakers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and the same problem. I didn't find any permanent solutions on the web. However, you can activate your 3.5 mm jack manually:

Type in terminal:

```
alsamixer
```

And now you can set speaker volume to 0%, and headphone volume to 100%.
I wrote 2 scripts that toggle headphone and speaker volume automatically:

This one is for headset:

```
#!/bin/bash
amixer set Headphone 100%
amixer set Speaker 0%
```

This one is for speaker:

```
#!/bin/bash
amixer set Headphone 0%
amixer set Speaker 100%
```

Then I accorded those scripts to keyboard shortcuts. The command for shortcut is:

```
gnome-terminal -e "path-to-script"
```

It's better than nothing.

I'll keep searching for a real solution to the problem and I'll share it here if I find.