# Headphones not working in 16.04 after upgrade from 14.04

Tags: sound, headphones

My Bluetooth speakers and laptop speakers work fine, but the headphone are not. When plugged in, the sounds comes from the laptop speakers. The headphones are fine and they work with other devices. I didn't have this problem with 14.04; I'd updated only three days ago.

Thanks.

Comment: This might be of help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working

Comment: Before trying the above link, wich might not be needed, check the following: Install PulseAudio running `sudo apt install pavucontrol` and select your headphones on the Output Devices section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread might be of help: 
[Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working?newreg=7f814973ce284e0a95dcc950b1ba6663)

You can see several suggestions for a solution, including one answer that adresses the issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thank you Tøffelen and @M. Becerra. Installing pavucontrol did the trick.