# Xubuntu Audio Jack not working

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, headphones, audio-jack

I already looked through the forums, but I couldn't find any thing that fixed two of my problems. For the sake of future reference, my computer is a P670 from Eluktronics. I have already contacted their support, but they don't know GNU+Linux.

The audio jack is not being recognized. I tried these first, third, and fourth [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working) but to no avail, the second one looks promising but I have no idea what to put in it due to my computer.

Also, calling pavucontrol returns the following:

```
** (pavucontrol:2152): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-OMd9I6Wf3q: Connection refused
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am seriously stumped on the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if pavucontrol gui does not start, we need fix that first. Somehow, I believe that the line you quote is just a warning about pavucontrol. does the gui show up?  That same warning appears for many GTK based programs.

The sound answer is almost always that the output device is muted or has volume O. When you attack this, think of it like a radio plugged into a stereo plugged into a tv. If any one is volume 0, no sound. Your player might send signal to a generic channel. Pavucontrol last pane options might help control. Also, you can control if jack is on.

You might be able to see this if you play song in rhythmbox. Launch pavucontrol from  terminal and look see is the sound is registered there, in output panel. You may see sound indicator but hear nothing because wrong output selected. (May send to internal device speakers, even if no speakers exist. when song is playong, sound meter line should bounce in output window. In the panels, you'll see lots of choices to turn off or on. Keep banging on it. Sometimes still I have easier time with alsa-mixer, you more easily see devices are off or volume 0. If you run alsa-mixer, gui is more primative. Muted channels say M. If is very possible your system has both alsa sound device and pulseaudio, if you hear nothing out of pulse, perhaps alsa is in charge.

Another part of problem is that different player software will send signal to different outputs. So far from your story, we dont even know for sure your player is a pulse audio device. Instead, it might be sending to alsa device.

I suppose the type of sound card matters too. If you don't find volume control fix, post again with output from lspci. That might give hint.

Write back, if you tell more, I'll remember more. Spent lots of time on it in the  old days, when sound cards were costly.  We fought this all the time. Can you imagine I paid $255 for a sound card in 2002. Of course, a computer ccost $3500 then ;)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the pavucontrol, it starts fine, the problem is when I go to select the device to play out to, the line isn't detected. Youtube will play fine to the speakers if that helps. Messing with the config for pavucontrol doesn't change anything.  AlsaMixer says I have a "HDA Intel PCH" card and a "Realtek ALC898" Chip, if that helps at all.

Comment: This is what lspci output >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>


00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5910 (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)

Comment: 00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)

Comment: 00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)

Comment: 00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)

Comment: 00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile] (rev a1)

Comment: 6d:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
6d:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
6e:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
6f:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961

Comment: Thanks to stack exchange I had to place that in multiple comments