# Headphones do not work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, alsa, headphones

So, I use only linux for work and I am quite noob with it and the headphones did not work when I got reformatted my computer. First the problem was that when they were connected neither the headphones sounded nor the speakers. I tried a all the solutions in this post: [Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working)

And now even with the headphones connected the sound comes out of the speakers.
I found this solution with modifiying the pin:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317239

But I cannot open the HDA-analyzer from Alsa. 
I type:

```
sudo python run.py
```

And get the error message and no GUI:

```
Please, install pygtk2 or python-gtk package
Using temporary directory: /dev/shm/hda-analyzer
You may remove this directory when finished or if you like to
download the most recent copy of hda-analyzer tool.
File cached /dev/shm/hda-analyzer/hda_analyzer.py
File cached /dev/shm/hda-analyzer/hda_guilib.py
File cached /dev/shm/hda-analyzer/hda_codec.py
File cached /dev/shm/hda-analyzer/hda_proc.py
File cached /dev/shm/hda-analyzer/hda_graph.py
File cached /dev/shm/hda-analyzer/hda_mixer.py
Downloaded all files, executing hda_analyzer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dev/shm/hda-analyzer/hda_analyzer.py", line 32, in <module>
    import gobject
ImportError: No module named gobject
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Did you read the first line occasion the message? It prompts you to install pygtk2 or python-gt.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I did say I am quite new to this. Thanks.
I managed to enter the GUI but I could not change the PIN, but looking for solutions I found this one with enabling the auto-mute in Alsamixer which worked like a Charm.
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/08/ubuntu-14-04-sound-headphone-speakers/ 
Thanks a lot anyway Marc, hopefully I learned something from this.