# ASUS ROG G751JY headphones/external speakears are not recognized (JACK PORT ISSUE)

Tags: alsa, headphones, audio-jack

As a title says, I'm struggling with headphones, external speakers jack port. For some reason, whatever I plugin via jack port, it is not recognized.

So far I was doing my best to fix this issue. I did everything I could, check alsamixer, adding some code lines into my sound config (/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf)...

Here's a link [Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working))! I'have already tried.

At the moment, I'm out of options, if anyone has any idea what to do, I would be grateful.

Hope someone has at least an idea what to do, because I really don't want to reinstall Ubuntu or even to install some other type of Linux such as Fedora, Debian ...

Comment: Sometimes I face such issue when wrong  output device is select. Check it in Sound Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally I fixed this HUGE *bug*. All you need to do (**only if you are using ASUS notebook**) is to write down this lines of code:

1. Open your terminal
2. Write down this line into your terminal

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
   ```
3. Once text file is opened at the bottom just add this line:

   ```
   options snd_hda_intel model=asus-mode4
   ```
4. Reboot

Comment: asus rog rezphyrus, did not help

Comment: Same config as @IvanShelonik, did not work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution on [launchpad][1].

You install hdajackretask,
then select at the top the Realtek codec, 
in options you enable "unconnected pins",
Find and enable Pin 0x16 Override and select "Headphone"
  "apply now", and you restart the computer.

It would tell me that the device was busy, but it still worked after rebooting.

Some people needed to kill pulseaudio and prevent it from restarting to make it work [(see this link)][2] but all in all, it worked.

Hope it helps, bye!