# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS - Other side can't hear from headset

Tags: 18.04, alsa

When i plugin headset in the jack and open any audio/video, I'm able to hear the audio being played. While when i connect to skype, bluejeans and do audio testing, i am unable to hear my own voice. Unfortunately one of my interview was messed out due to this issue. Can you please help me and let me know if you need any other details?

I've tried multiple links [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9YxMHIRDoY) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working) as well but that didn't helped. Volume under settings - sound - input and output are full and not mute.

Here are the laptop details:

```
System Information
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Product Name: Latitude E7450
Version: Not Specified
Serial Number: 
UUID: 4C4C4544-0011-2019-1101-C7C04F383832
Wake-up Type: Power Switch
SKU Number: 062E
Family: Not Specified
```

Comment: Probably nothing to do with Ubuntu. If your computer has two connections, one for headphones and another for microphone and your headset has only one plug you need an adapter.

Comment: No that isn't the case. When i work without headset i.e. relying upon internal microphone it just works. The problem is then the other side complains that their voice is echoing. I'm sure there would be a way to connect headset and I might be missing something in config.

Comment: You're missing compatibility. It's your headset, not Ubuntu.

Comment: What connections do you have in the laptop? Better post brand/model as well.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia have added details in the question. Please let me know if you need further any details. I'm not sure what you mean by connections, if you have any command and you need any output for the same then let me know.

Comment: It has a combo connection, apparently. It should work either the headset/earphone typical for (most) Android phones or the ones for (old) iphones OR the connection if for headphones only (locking closely it does show headphones only).

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia any idea then what could that i be missing?