# Headphones Detected, but audio coming out of speakers

Tags: sound, 19.04, headphones

Using Ubuntu 19.04, dual boot with Windows 10, on an Alienware. A couple of months back I had to reinstall 19.04 (before the reinstallation audio worked fine), because of another issue I had. After the fresh install speakers worked fine, but when I plug my headphones (which I know work) audio is still coming out of the speakers. Headphones are detected (I can see them in pavucontrol). Any ideas?
Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings->sound and choose device you want the audio to play on. If you don't change it back later it will automatically play on headphones if you unplug and plug them back

Comment: With headphones unplugged I have one option: "Speakers - Built-in Audio". With headphones plugged I also have one option" "Headphones - Built-in Audio". Plugging or unplugging doesn't change that the sound always comes from the speakers.

Comment: If there is only one option in settings that means they are not detected. I would try these: (https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working)

Comment: I have tried all these. The only thing that I don't know is if in the command `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6-amic`, where I replace `dell-m6-amic` with `6stack-dig` (I found it on another forum) is the right one. 
Also the headphones are detected in a way because the option changes in the settings when I plug them in.

Comment: Is the second device playing sound device using HDMI? Could you try to disconnect it and try headphones? It is strange but such issue with HDMI audio devices is possible

Comment: The devices shown are Speakers and Headphones, there is no HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings (lower left button in the first image)

[image]

Select Sound from the left menu

In the right side, In the output drop down list, select your preferred output device.

[image]

Comment: As I wrote on the comment above I always have one option and the sound always comes from the speakers