# No sound from headphones even though they have been detected

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have an Alienware M17x R4, Ubnutu 18.04. My internal speakers and bluetooth headphones work fine, but when I plug headphones in, sound continues to come through the internal peakers.

I have tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working) and also tried

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m4-1 enable_msi=1
options snd-hda-intel model=6stack-dig
```

(IIRC the first of these is from when I had the same problem a while ago, it looks like some update process commented that out and put in the second one.)

What's odd is that when I plug in my headphones, this is dynamically recognised in `pavucontrol`

[image]

and this widget shows volume feedback when sound plays. So it looks like the software believes it is outputting to headphones, although it is not.

How do I fix this?