# Permanently fix "headphones with no sound issue" instead of manually fixing it every time you plug in headphones

Tags: sound, 20.04, alsa, headphones

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04, on a Dell XPS 13.

Every time I plug in my headphones, all sound is muted.

Following instructions in other posts here, I do `alsactl restore`, which enables both my headphones and my built-in laptop speakers. I then have to go to `alsamixer` to manually switch off my speakers, so that I can actually get sound out of my headphones, and exclusively out of my headphones. One would expect this would happen automatically when you plug in your headphones.

As mentioned, the other posts here explain how to solve this manually by doing the above every time you plug in your headphones. For that reason I don't believe this post is a duplicate. Many users would like to know how to solve this problem permanently.

How do we permanently fix the above issue?

Comment: Might help to add the specific type of your computer: `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` I sporadically had to run alsactrl restore on a 9350, but I never have the issue anymore on a 7390.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue.

You can use `alsactl store` when you have correct configuration (headphones on and speakers off), so that `alsactl restore` can load that configuration later, and then follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1239406/1103211).