# Kdenlive Error - Could not create the video preview window

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, kdenlive

The headphone jack on my Ubuntu 20.04 system would not work until I [read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working) and issued this command:

```
alsactl restore
```

Since then my headphone jack has been working fine. The problem is that the solution above broke something with my Kdenlive v20.04.01 Snap install. Whenever I boot Kdenlive I now get the following error:

> *Error - Kdenlive. Could not create the video preview window. There is something wrong with your Kdenlive install or your driver settings. Please fix it.*

What do I do to ensure both my headphone jack, and Kdenlive, both work?

I did a purge uninstall of Kdenlive (also removing `~/cache/kdenlive`, `~/local/share/kdenlive`, and `~/.config/kdenliverc`) but this did not get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 and had installed Kdenlive via snap. When I tried to open kdenlive via terminal the splash indicated that the problem is with pulseaudio. Somehow, kdenlive snap isn't able to detect pulseaudio.

You can try two things to make Kdenlive work:

1. Make sure that pulseaudio is working
2. [Run Kdenlive via it's appimage](https://kdenlive.org/en/download)

The second solution solved my issue.

Comment: Shihab, the appimage worked for me but do I have to open it via appimage every time or can I somehow replace my kdenlive version found in the app drawer?

Answer (score 0):

Good evening all,

I don't know if you ladies/gentlemen have found an answer to the above problem but, I have been dealing with the very same problem for the last 20dd or so.

The problem is "Where the "kdenliverc" file is located on the KDENLIVE installation manual instructs that "Kdenlive's application-wide persistent settings are stored in the following locations, depending on your platform."

In my case, I am using Linux Mint 19.3

So, the "kdenliverc" file was not located on ~/.config/kdenliverc

Instead, it was on "/home/username/.var/app/org.kde.kdenlive/config/kdenliverc"
According to more experienced Linux users is due to the fact that I am using Flaptpack but the most important is the issue was resolved

Once I have erased the file (according to KDEnlive online Manual) It came back just fine!!
[image: Solved]
How the crash would appear to me

I hope I have helped

[image: The error Message]

[![Problem solved][2]][2]

Comment: Can you be clear on what file you deleted?

Comment: Sure and I apologize for the delay. The nime of the file is "kdenliverc"