# A problem with headphones: the audio is reproduced both by speakers and headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones, speakers, pavucontrol

At the beginning my headphones didn't work. In Settings/Sound the only output device is the pair of speakers. After having tried certain commands related to [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working) I have installed `pavucontrol` but now my headphones **work in parallel with the speakers**. Maybe pavucontrol is not the best idea but I don't know.

I would like to have my headphones behave correctly i.e. when I insert the jack the audio is switched from the speakers to the headphones.

How can I fix this problem?

My ubuntu version is 20.10.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem a stereo *male* jack adapter is mandatory. In this way Ubuntu should recognize headphones/headsets.