# No sound in headphones after reconnecting

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have Ubuntu 18.04 (dual boot with Windows 10). Headphones work properly in Windows 10. In Ubuntu, if the headphones are connected before starting ubuntu, it works fine. But if I remove the headphone and then connect them again, no sound comes in the headphone, though, I can see the output device in settings.

I have tried multiple solutions in this and other forums (like the ones described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/132440/775359)). Most of the questions say headphones not working. But my problem is slightly different. They work after rebooting the machine. But if I unplug them and plug them again, they won't work. I have to restart the machine again.

Is there any solution to fix this problem? Is it possible to reinstall drivers, if that may help? I can provide any extra information, if needed

Comment: You see headphones as output device in settings - but are they selected? Can you select them manually? If yes, do headphones work after you select them manually or not?

Comment: I can see headphones in settings. I can select them. But like I said, if I haven't reconnected the headphones after restart, I get sound in them. Otherwise no sound. When I select headphones in settings, sound from speakers stops. If I select speakers back, I get sound again